# High refresh rates (90-120-144-165 Hz) for Androdi studio AVD (Android Virtual Device Manager) emulators

Tags: android, android-studio, android-emulator, android-virtual-device, frame-rate

So I am using a monitor with higher 165Hz refresh rate and I was wondering if I can increase the emulator refresh rate from 60 to 120 or even higher because why not? and I have a rtx3060 graphic card as well which can support the extra fps and create smoother experience.

I did search online and surprisingly didn't find any AVD related answer.

I am not sure if, I didn't search correctly or it's not possible yet with android studio AVD.

Answer (score -1):

This might or might not work !

So I found this on Samsung's website [Emulator Skins for S21 Ultra and more](https://developer.samsung.com/galaxy-emulator-skin/guide.html) am pretty sure the newer devices have higher refresh rate and if these are authentic skins definitely they might have support for higher refresh rates, If I were you I would have tested it (I couldn't do it right now as the device that I am using currently only supports 60hz).

[Guide to Use Samsung Skins in Android Studio](https://developer.samsung.com/galaxy-emulator-skin/guide.html)

Comment: thank you for your help, It didn't work but at least I have a cooler emulator skin. the reason this didn't work is that these skins only change the frame around the emulator and does nothing to the actual android OS or it's settings. to achieve this goal there should be something added to android or emulator display settings to add custom refresh rate which is not that easy I think, it takes some developing to add this feature I guess. but if anyone know a workaround for it that would be cool.

Comment: yeah seems like some developer level update is required, anyway now you have a cool skin :D